# How to use clone() in C++ with multiple inheritance of abstract classes?

Tags: c++, clone, abstract, pure-virtual

I am working on a C++ program, but I am having problem with multiple inheritance when using cloning. The problem (in a simplified form) is the following.

I want to be able to clone all objects derived from the class Base.

```
class Base{
public:

    virtual Base* clone()const=0;
};
```

I want to define two other classes derived from Base, which are both abstract, i.e. I cannot define the clone function, but I have to declare them in some way (I want to make sure, that if I clone Derived*, I will get back Derived* and not Base*, i.e. I want to avoid casting at the point of application)

```
class Derived1: public virtual Base{
public:
    virtual Derived1* clone()const=0;
};

class Derived2: public virtual Base{
public:
    virtual Derived2* clone()const=0;
};
```

The problem comes, when I declare a fourth class, which is inherited from both Derived1 and Derived2:

```
class Derived3: public Derived1,public Derived2{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    Derived3():b(3){};
    Derived3(Derived3 const& l_B) {b=l_B.b;};
    virtual Derived3* clone()const{return new Derived3(*this);}
    ;
};
```

In this case I will get from Visual C++ 2010 compiler C2250: 'Derived3' : ambiguous inheritance of 'Derived1 *Base::clone(void) const'. If I declare clone() in Derived1 and Derived2 not pure virtual, but without definition, the error remains the same:

```
class Base{
public:

    virtual Base* clone()const=0;
};

class Derived1: public virtual Base{
public:
    virtual Derived1* clone()const;
};



class Derived2: public virtual Base{
public:
    virtual Derived2* clone()const;
};

class Derived3: public Derived1,public Derived2{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    Derived3():b(3){};
    Derived3(Derived3 const& l_B) {b=l_B.b;};
    virtual Derived3* clone()const{return new Derived3(*this);}
    ;
};
```

Using virtual inheritance at Derived3 will not help either, and I cannot find a way to solve it, I simply run out of ideas. It is very important that all classes should return a pointer of the same type, e.g. I want to do later:

```
Derived3 test;
Derived1* test2=&test;
Derived1* test3=test2->clone();
```

and I want to avoid:

```
Derived3 test;
Derived1* test2=&test;
Derived1* test3=dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(test2->clone());
```

If anyone has an idea or solution, I would appreciate it!

Comment: If you were not using multiple unheritance, this behavior is typically achieved through the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Polymorphic_copy_construction)...I haven't been able to get it to behave with the multiple inheritance though. multiple inheritance is the devil.

Comment: Looks like a bug in MSVC (no suprise there).  Since the base classes are virtual, there is no ambiguity.  You should probably make Derived1 and Derived2 virtual bases in Derived3 as well, in case you want to add more classes later.  You could try using a newer version of MSVC as the bug may have been fixed.

Comment: But you ABSOLUTELY need to have virtual inheritance for Dirived3, else your vtable is going to have multiple copies of the Base functions. The compilers confusion is understandable: it has no way of knowing what behavior to do if you do dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(test2)->clone().

Comment: Confirming Chris Dodd, gcc 4.7.2, clang 3.2, Intel C++ 2013.3 are all happy with this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea would be to have a protected virtual method `clone_impl` in `Base` and a public non-virtual `clone`:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    virtual Base* clone_impl() const = 0;

public:
    Base* clone() const
    {
      return clone_impl();
    }
};
```

and for *each* derived class provide `clone_impl` when the class is *not* abstract and a non-virtual wrapper `clone` for *all* derived classes:

```
class DerivedX : ...
{
protected:
    // only when not abstract:
    virtual Base* clone_impl() const
    {
      return new DerivedX(*this);
    }

public:
    // in each derived class
    DerivedX* clone() const
    {
      return static_cast<DerivedX*>(clone_impl());
    }
};
```