# How can two inheriting classes call each other's methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child

If 2 classes are inheriting 1 base class, then how can these two child classes call each other's functions? 
As in, how can one child class object call another child class' function?

Comment: You cannot call a method of another derived class only by inheriting from the same base class. Maybe you can provide an example, what you are doing?

Comment: Can you show us an example? Often this means the interface needs a redesign.

Comment: Sounds like you resolve this situation with a better code structure. If the method is shared functionality, it could be abstracted out into its own class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using virtual member functions.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base { // abstract base class
    virtual void func_1(Base&) = 0;
    virtual void func_2(Base&) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

Base::~Base() {} // to not force children to have to implement the destructor

// child classes, overriding the necessary virtual functions in the base class
struct One : Base {
    void func_1(Base& o) override {
        std::cout << "One calling some Base descendant\n";
        o.func_2(*this); // here, one child is calling another
    }

    void func_2(Base& o) override {}
};

struct Two : Base {
    void func_1(Base& o) override {}

    void func_2(Base& o) override { 
        std::cout << "Two called\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    One o;
    Two t;
    o.func_1(t);
}
```

Output:

```
One calling some Base descendant
Two called
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't.
The two objects will both **extend** the **base** class' members, so they will have the same members and attributes, but they will not have any other add-on characteristics.

Somewhat fun analogy: when they say the children have their mother's eyes, they don't mean they actually have her eyes, they just have genetically perfect copies of them, individual copies at that.

See this, if you're referring to references of child classes:
[How to use clone() in C++ with multiple inheritance of abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575272/how-to-use-clone-in-c-with-multiple-inheritance-of-abstract-classes)